# Can't kill process TGitCache.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows, git, process-explorer, tortoise-git

Sometimes, I suspect when I open a music folder during the right moon phase and during a leap microsecond, this process crashes and pops up an error reporting dialogue. I decline to report the error, because that also fails by now, and choose Exit. Exit just delays the re-appearance  of the error reporting dialogue for about 2 seconds.

If I try and kill the process using SysInternals' Process Explorer the process is just restarted, only to crash again. So, I'm pretty sure another process, probably a service because TGitCache doesn't have a parent process and no other Git processes are visible, is keeping tabs on this process and restarting it if it dies. This is cruel and inhuman, but how can I find which nanny process is prolonging the agony?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process seems to be 'TortoiseGit for Windows' which looks like a client for Apache.

"TortoiseSVN is an easy-to-use SCM / source control software for Microsoft Windows and possibly the best standalone Apache™ Subversion®client there is. It is implemented as a Windows shell extension, which makes it integrate seamlessly into the Windows explorer. Since it's not an integration for a specific IDE you can use it with whatever development tools you like." [Source](http://tortoisesvn.net/about.html).

There's a fix [here](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=48) which is a setting change of "TortoiseGit->setting -> Icon Overlays choose "Shell" or "None" to disable 
TGitCache.exe."

Comment: Of if you know you are not using Apache then just uninstall it! ;)

Comment: thanks, I'll try different Overlays settings, but where does your second paragraph fit in? I have nothing to do with TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Second paragraph is from the softwares webpage, tells you what it does so thought it might help you to identify it! :)

Comment: Note: I've never used (or even looked at) TortoiseGit so apologies if any of this information is inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agree with @HaydnWVN: Uninstall this. If you don't know what it is, you are definitely not using it, and are better off uninstalling it.

Next, for those still seeing this problem, I believe the error is more closely related to this  [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=950) which is supposed to be fixed in TortoiseGit 1.7.5.0.

However, I'm still seeing it on r1.7.7.0, so if anyone has more info, that's still much appreciated.